# For cycle in Python's way in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop

May seem stupid, but after using Matlab for a while (a couple of years), I've tried Python, and despite some Matlab's features that are really handy, I really like Python.

Now, for work, I'm using Matlab again, and sometimes I miss a structure like Python's 'for' loop. Instead of using the standard 'for' that Matlab provides, there is a structure more similar to process batches of similar data?

Comment: @JohanLundberg I know what a for loop is, simply I thought that the Matlab for loop was the same as C one. Thank you anyway

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohanLundberg my question was based on a wrong assumption that I was making, so I didn't know what to look for; anyway if I'll receive complaints I'll delete it.

Comment: @JohanLundberg but politeness is not your strongest point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
for val = {'Hello', 'world', '!'}
    disp(val)
end

for val = [1 3 6 9]
    disp(val)
end
```

Comment: oh that's nice! but can I also parse an existing array?

Comment: Yes, after Clement's answer, I looked to the documentation and tried it, so I've found how it works. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, the 'standard' usage of `for` (with index) is just a particular case of its usage.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answer, be aware that MATLAB's `for`loop is very slow.

Maybe programming in a functional style using `arrayfun`, `cellfun()` and `structfun()` might be a handier solution, and quite close to Python's `map()`.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't aware of that! But, and sorry for my ignorance, it's true only for long arrays, not for small arrays of big items, right?

Comment: I don't know. I use them quite often, but I haven't made any tests concerning the execution speed variability...

Comment: In modern Matlab versions, `for` loops are not slow themselves. It's the overhead of the repeated operations done inside the loop body. The `arrayfun`, `cellfun`, and `structfun` functions are all iterative, too, not "vectorized", and will often be as slow as a for loop; in some cases, worse because they prevent the JIT from doing in-place optimizations or have other overhead. To be fast, you need to structure data and code to call vectorized operations which apply builtin functions across an entire array. Speed aside, the `xxxfun()` functions are great.